# OpenVPN don't route a specific IP address

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Would like to prevent a specific subnet (say `200.*.*.*`) from routing. Don't have access to the OpenVPN server config, can modify only the client-side config. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a more-specific route for that address (i.e. with netmask 255.255.255.255 if it's a single address). This will automatically have priority over any less-specific routes that the client receives from the server.

The easiest way to do this is by using OpenVPN's own `route` command, as there you can specify `net_gateway` as the gateway address and let OpenVPN determine which gateway to use:

```
route 200.x.x.x 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```